# insuffient dont have enough space on my sd card

Tags: google-play-store, data-connection

When I'm trying to download samthing it says "insuffient space on my device"my brean it does work when I hear that......it so confusing me..and I have engh space on my memory card

Comment: Could you provide more information? Phone Model? Internal Storage Space (Used and Max)? Do you have an SD Card?

Comment: happens to mine phone too!

Answer (score 0):

i just figured out exactly what is giving me insufficient memory. it is my voicemail to text just delete your trash and the message is gone i am able to redownload apps i uninstalled. if anyone has a LG phone thats my solution if you have the voicemail to text maybe try my solution.